# PHP Fatal error failed opening required file

Tags: entities

I am trying to build a site with Organic Groups (a site like myfamily.com, with the groups being individual families), and I am getting a persistent PHP Fatal error

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
/var/www/.../sites/all/modules/addressfield/addressfield.install
 (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/viewstest
/includes/module.inc on line 330
```

I am getting a WSOD when I try to navigate to the site. I have tried clearing caches, I have tried [registry rebuild](https://drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild), No luck. My backup is also experiencing the same issues, so I am not sure what is going on.

I have seem some references to this but cannot come up with a firm answer as how to fix. Does anyone know what is happening and how I might go about fixing this?

I have also posted on d o : https://drupal.org/node/2278519 .

Comment: Just a guess, what if you disable addressfield, uninstall it and then see if the WSOD goes away. `drush dis addressfield` and `drush pm-uninstall addressfield`  If that works then try re-enabling it agian. Also check your Apache logs, sometimes there's very specific errors there that point to the issue that don't show up in Drupal watchdog.

Comment: Hi @DannyEnglander thanks for that, but I tried disabling and it said I couldn't because there was a field in use. The error message is straight from the Apache logs. The message from Drush is "addressfield is a required module and can't be disabled. Reason: Field type(s) in use - see Field list". It's been quite a catch-22. What's more, other modules are now reporting the same error (also in Apache error logs). Very frustrating.

Comment: Obvious question, but does the file actually exist, and is readable by webserver user, at: `/var/www/.../sites/all/modules/addressfield/addressfield.install` ?

Comment: sorry for late reply @DavidThomas death in the family. Yes, file exists, and permissions appear to be OK. 644 for files, 755 for directories, same owner and group as with all my other Drupal 7 instances on same local dev environment. Still puzzling over this.